# ASP.NET Core - How to get parameter from url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Below is a code that displays my shop item url to my users. The URL (@model.URl) displayed to my user looks like the

```
https://api.com/folder/?productid=000100&urlProvider=2k4&search=pc
```

Is there any way i can display the **urlProdiver** paramater alone in my view like

```
<a href="@Model.Url["urlProvider"]">

</a>
```

**ShopItem.cs**

```
public class ShopItem
{
   public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

**ShopItem.cshtml**

```
@model ShopItem

<a href="@Model.Url">

</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` and convert your `string` `Model.Url` to `Uri` object and use like below.

```
<a href='@HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri(Model.Url)).Get("urlProvider");'>
    
</a>
```

<sub>Namespace: System.Web

Assembly: System.Web.HttpUtility.dll</sub>

Comment: Nice.  Actually i want the `a href` to be the urlProvider instead. Is it that possible ?

Comment: Yes, just move code to `href` as per updated answer.